# Any solution about using GIT submodule between main server and local server?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am looking for a solution for this scenario.

1. Server:
   Main server: All teams pull code from it. Only admins in team can push to main server.
   Local servers: Every team has their only local server which mirrors the main server. And team members pull/push code from/to local server.
2. Projects:
   We have several designs will be reused in new project. So plan to use submodule. But in the above server structure, how should we add submodules and mirror the super project between servers?

From my understanding, the submodule's URL is pointing to a fix location. But hope each team member can only access the submodules from their local server. Do not expect massive or frequent manual change configuration files for everyone. Expecting solutions and suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> From my understanding, the submodule's URL is pointing to a fix location

Yes, but that URL is registered in a `.gitmodules` file (like [for my project](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/.gitmodules)), so each developer can, in his/her own branch, have its own version of that file, with the right URLs, referring to mirrors of the submodule repo on the local servers.
That is, if they have to push modifications to those submodules repos. Because if they don't, they could reference those submodule repos directly on the main server.